# Informix generate query from other query (eval results to SELECT) - PHP and Informix

Tags: php, sql, select, eval, informix

First, just simple question: Is there something as "EVAL()" function in Informix?

And now if anyone is interested there is real world problem where I need EVAL() function:

So, I have two tables in DB:

- Fist table (main one) is **sales_data**(data_id, data_val_id, other, columns, ...)
- Second table is **for_select**(data_id, select_part, from_part, where_part, key_column_name)

Problem is that in first table I don't have all data that I need. Additional data is in other tables depending on "data_id" and "data_val_id" columns in first table.

So, second table is for creating SQL SELECT to get those additional data from other tables.

Now I need to create SQL query like this (but I think that there is no EVAL function in Informix):

```
SELECT 
    data_id, 
    data_val_id, 
    (SELECT 
          EVAL(SELECT select_part FROM for_select WHERE data_id=sales_data.data_id)
     FROM
          EVAL(SELECT from_part FROM for_select WHERE data_id=sales_data.data_id)
     WHERE
          EVAL(SELECT where_part FROM for_select WHERE data_id=sales_data.data_id)
          AND
          EVAL(SELECT key_column_name FROM for_select WHERE data_id=sales_data.data_id) = sales_data.data_val_id
     ) AS additional_data
FROM
    sales_data
```

I don't know who came up with this idea but it is not mine and I can't chage it...

I did tried to do this in PHP with dynamic SQL queries but it is veeery slow. For every row in results from main table PHP must connect to server and send new query. It is very slow and in main table I have around 50000 rows and I have 4 more this "additional_data" columns (grand total 5 "data_id" and "data_val_id" columns in main table).

Can someone help me? Is this posible in one SELECT? Is there something as "EVAL()" function in Informix?

-------- more explanations ---------

Every row in `for_select` table is very diferent from each other. Data in `sales_data` table is from our selling (our job) and final report (joined main and additional data) must have all columns. This is something that we can't change, report must look how it looks now and must have all data that have now. I just need to find a way to export it quicker than now.

I will try to write example: In DB we have tables for warehouses, for goods, for clients, for workers, for cars, ... and every row in `for_select` table is for one of this tables. Table `for_select` have 54 rows, so this means that we have 54 tables that we need additional data from to put in final report.

In `sales_data` we only have 5 columns that can be used for 5 diferent things depending on `data_id` column but I have 54 posible "things" that can be there, so comination of `data_id` (what table is used for "additional data") and `data_val_id` (what row from that table) determine what will be in final report. In real life `data_id` is for diferent type of goods that we sell and therefore for every diferent goods we need to show diferent "additional data" in addition to basic data: number of selled items, price,...

So, why we need `for_select` table, you ask? Because every table for additional data have diferent names for columns and in diferent place. Table `cars` have `car_id`, `car_model` columns but table `warehouses` have `wh_id`,`wh_location` and `wh_name` columns, from `cars` table I ony need `car_model` column but from `warehouses` I need `wh_location||wh_name` together (concated).

Tables names and data are in Serbian and names are not informative at all, so I did my best to translate it to English so you all can understand. Raw data will just confuse you all...

Comment: The EVAL notation isn't going to fly in Informix; I'm not sure which of the mainstream SQL DBMS will support the notation shown, but I think the answer is 'very few of them'. Generating a new SELECT statement for each row in a table, using 4 other SELECT statements for each, is going to be ridiculously slow.  You have, IMO, serious design issues.  I don't know who designed the system that can't be changed, and I'd like to know which system it actually performs well on with 50k rows.  You could use dynamic SQL to piece together strings that can then be executed, but the performance will be bad.

Comment: Roughly speaking: time to rethink the whole game.

Comment: Well... this is used in our ERP at work. ERP have report for this data but it is very slow (when I start exporting all data) and I thought that slowness comes from exporting data directly to Excel, but now I know that slowness is because of all this complication with tables and dynamic queries.

I have idea to first put "additional data" to RAM table(s) and join it with main data, I hope then it will be faster...

Comment: How much do the different rows in the `for_select` table vary between rows?  Who decides on the content for each row in the `sales_data` table?  Can you show 5 representative rows from `for_select`?  What is the basis for choosing the information that's in the `for_select` table for each given row?

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). For an SQL question, that will include at least outline table schemas, and some sample data, and expected output from the sample data. I'm not clear on the final output from your SELECT; it may be that it has 15 columns, 5 sets of 'data_id, data_val_id, data_value', where 'data_value' is the result of your putative 'EVAL-based SELECT'. But then it isn't clear where the `data_id` and `data_val_id` values come from; presumably that's `sales_data`, but you've not shown outline schema/data for that table. Do note that the M in MCVE is for minimal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
I did my best to explain everything, but now I don't have time this week to create examples, sorry.
Column names, table names and data in them are in Serbian language. I tried to translate them to english but it is not good... so I did this simple explanation and example in my first question.
And, YES, columns `data_id` and `data_val_id` are from `sales_data` table (it is not only sales data in table, but all financy data) and are not needed in final report, I forget to say that. In final report I need (beside main data) `data_value` that is result from dynamic SQL SELECT.

Comment: This isn't garnering world-wide attention, so you could leave it unchanged until you've time to provide some extra information.  Or you could delete it (keep a copy of the info before you delete it, just in case), and then edit and undelete it when you have more information.  I'm willing to help; I just need some clarity.  I'm sorry I can't work in Serbian with you.  Add an `@Jonathan` comment to this if you delete and undelete it, or if you simply leave it alone for a while and want me to come look.  Just make sure it is as ready as possible before pinging me, please.